# AWS CloudFormation - can I use Sub inside GetAtt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, security-groups

I'm trying to reference a security group inside a CloudFormation template.

the name of the group is `!Sub '${EnvironmentName}-SG-Private`, where EnvironmentName is a template parameter.

However, the `DBInstance` AWS type requires the `GroupId` of the security group, not the group name.  So I'm trying to use GetAtt to retrieve it, but without any luck:

`Fn::GetAtt: [$(Fn::Sub:[${EnvironmentName}-SG-Private]), GroupId]`

This and various other permutations all caused errors.

Reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html), it says

> For the Fn::GetAtt logical resource name, you cannot use functions. You must specify a string that is a resource's logical ID.

If I've read that right, the problem cannot be solved the way I'm trying to do so.
So how am I supposed to reference this security group?  Do I need to export its GroupId at group creation time?

Comment: Great tips here https://garbe.io/blog/2017/07/17/cloudformation-hacks/

Answer (score 0):

Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function returns the value of an attribute from a resource in the template. For more information about GetAtt return values for a particular resource, refer to the documentation for that resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `Fn::GetAtt` with resources in the same template. Hence you can’t use it on names derived from template parameters.

If you need the `GroupId` you can export it from the template that creates the Security Group and `Fn::ImportValue` it in the template that needs it.

For more info see [**CloudFormation Export / ImportValue**](https://aws.nz/best-practice/cloudformation-exports/)

Hope that helps :)